# Why does this Arduino while loop never end?

Tags: while-loop, arduino

This may be the worst way of doing this but I want the Arduino to pick between 1 and -1. This code is not working, what is wrong.

This is my understanding of the code:

- The int is defined as 0.
- The while loop starts because the condition is true.
- A random variable is chosen.
- If the int is 1 or -1 then the while loop ends and the value is
  printed.
- If the int is 0 the while loop restarts.

  ```
  int random_number = 0;

   void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     while (random_number == 0){
         int random_number = random(-1,2);
         Serial.println(random_number);
         delay(1000);
     }
     Serial.print("value ");
     Serial.println(random_number);
   }

   void loop() {
   }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are declaring `random_number` inside the while loop again. This is a new and different variable in the local scope of the loop, not the one declared globaly at the begining of your code. Also, it is being declared again on every loop.

```
 int random_number = 0;

 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   while (random_number == 0){
       random_number = random(-1,2); // not declared again
       Serial.println(random_number);
       delay(1000);
   }
   Serial.print("value ");
   Serial.println(random_number);
 }

 void loop() {
 }
```

Note that `int random_number` is replaced by `random_number` inside the loop. Now the globally declared variable `random_number` is being used instead of declaring a new local variable with the same name.

Comment: Is your solution to move the first line inside the setup function? This still does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a little clarity to [eventHandler's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660807/9646577) (correct) response, since there appears to still be confusion for someone reading it:

The problem lies in the line

```
int random_number = random(-1,2);
```

because by including a *type specifier* (the `int` declarator), a new variable called `random_number` is being declared **within the scope of** the `while` loop. This variable, as pointed out before, is not the same as the one declared globally in the line

```
int random_number = 0;
```

thus it is not the one being used in the `while` loop condition.

Generally, multiple declaration is flagged by the compiler as being an issue, but since the variables in the question have different scopes, what is actually being done is called *shadowing*. Here, the `random_number` of the loop is hiding (or shadowing) the one declared in the global scope and so it is being assigned a random number instead of the intended variable. When variables with different scopes are being resolved, the "most local" one is given preference over the "least local" one.

The definition of `random_number` in the `while` loop should thus read:

```
random_number = random(-1,2);
```

in which case the global variable is being assigned a new value (instead of a new variable being assigned one), only one variable of that name exists in the code snippet, and the issue is resolved.